# Minimized child windows on VMWare Horizon app look weird

Tags: window, vmware-horizon

Not sure if this is the right site for this, but I have an Electron app that's running as a published app through VMWare Horizon.

This app has [child windows](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#parent-and-child-windows) that are owned by the parent and minimize to the bottom left corner of the primary monitor.

[image]

With VMware, this normally happens, but if the main (parent) window is not on the primary monitor, then we get a weird-looking toolbar that's behind all other applications on that monitor:

[image]

While the X button works, the other buttons don't, and you have to double-click the titlebar to restore the window.

Does VMWare just not work well with child windows like this? Is there some configuration that can fix this, or is this a known, tracked issue?